# Running testng mixed mode

Tags: testng

Is there option to run mixed mode from code that is instead of calling it in ant? ,directly in xml?

http://testng.org/doc/migrating.html

My usecase is , i have to run junit3,junit4 cases in testing same time.

Now iam generating xml dynamically from code like ,

XmlTest test = new XmlTest(suite);
 test.setName(testCase);
 test.setJunit(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mixed mode in Ant, or set the property to TestNG in code.

While using Ant the support is in the Ant task with "-mixed" option. You can find more details be reading history of implementation of this feature, see http://wiki.netbeans.org/wiki/index.php?title=TestNG_MixedMode

While set this by code, the flow is basically like below:

```
// Create TestNG instance then run the suite
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
// We want to run both JUnit and TestNG tests
tng.setMixed(true);
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
// Verbose mode will print summary
tng.setVerbose(1);
tng.run();
```

Another alternative solution I'm aware of is the one you're already using. Set JUnit to true in the code or in the  section in testng.xml.